# MIT Scheme Passing Messages Grade Table

Tags: scheme, message, procedure

At the moment, as part of an assignment, I am attempting to write a scheme program that accepts 3 messages, `'get-student-average` `'get-assignment-average` and `'add-grade`, and returns the information as necessary. `'add-grade` basically gives the student id, assignment, and grade as it is inserted in that order. I am still working on the student and assignment average messages (hence the semicolons in front of them), but what keeps failing when I try to run it is the `'add-grade` message. It keeps saying that grades is an unbound variable. This is the code that I am testing it with:

```
(define (make-grades)
  (define T '())
  (define (dispatch op)
    ((eq? op 'add-grade) (lambda(id as gr) (set! T (append T (list (list id as gr)
    )))))
   ;((eq? op 'get-student-average) (lambda(x) ( )))
   ;((eq? op 'get-assignment-average)
))

(define grades (make-grades))
((grades 'add-grade) 7 1 85))
```

I'm not sure what it is that I am doing wrong to try and get back the information with that. I thought that, as with tables in scheme, the trick is in appending the list as a list to a null value, then setting it.

There are a bunch of other test cases (including some for the `'average` messages), but I did not include them as I feel that it's just repeating more of the same. The one other thing I feel I should mention is that all of the test-cases are held together within a list, starting with `'(` and ending with `)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. For starters, you are not actually checking what message is being received (there should be a `cond` or a series of nested `if`s or a `case` somewhere). And you're not returning the dispatcher procedure. Here, try this to get started:

```
(define (make-grades)
  (define T '())
  (define (dispatch op)
    (cond ((eq? op 'add-grade)
           (lambda (id as gr)
             (set! T (append T (list (list id as gr))))))
          ;((eq? op 'get-student-average) (lambda(x) ( )))
          ;((eq? op 'get-assignment-average)
          ))
  dispatch)
```

Also, you should add a fourth message to return the list, for testing purposes.